# How to use html/css to align chat bubble paragraphs?

Tags: html, css

So I want to have a paragraph that could be one or more lines long that is on the right side of the page but is left aligned.

Example:

```
¦              Example text to show ¦
¦              where I want the     ¦   <-- Right side of page
¦              paragraph to be.     ¦
```

So I added a left margin and told the text to align to the left:

```
<p style="text-align: left; margin-left:>Text</p>
```

This works for long paragraphs; however, if the paragraph is less that a line long, it looks like this:

```
  ¦              Short Text           ¦
  ¦                                   ¦   <-- Right side of page
  ¦                                   ¦
```

instead of:

```
  ¦                         Short Text¦
  ¦                                   ¦   <-- Right side of page
  ¦                                   ¦
```

I then tried aligning the paragraph to the right and aligning the last line to the left:

```
<p style="text-align: right;text-align-last: left; margin-left: 200px">Text</p>
```

However, that resulted in text over-hanging:

```
¦               Example text to show¦
¦                   where I want the¦   <-- Right side of page
¦              paragraph to be.     ¦
```

Is there any way I can get the paragraph to be on the right of the page with all the lines lined up like in the first example, but not so that a short line will not be left in the middle of the page?

Comment: Do you have a visual example of the issue and what you want to achieve? It would help a lot.

Comment: I have added them but for some reason by question has been closed for being bad?

Comment: Yes, in these cases you should use images and code examples when starting the question.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please read our How to Ask page and then edit your question to improve it. It would be helpful to have a minimal reproducible example (including HTML) so it's easier/faster to others to respond with good answers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So, initially I hadn't understood your question correctly, but with your additional comments I reworked my answer and adjusted it to what you explained. I think it wasn't really clear in your question you needed that for a chat. I made an example with chat bubbles, the points are not ideal, just playing around :). But I think this solves your problem.

Basically you can't use just `p` elements for this, you need a main container  and a container for each message and you use `flex` and `align-self` on each inner container. Check the running example.

```css
#chat-container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  padding: 1rem;
}

.bubble {
  border: solid 1px #DDD;
  background: #EEE;
  margin-bottom: 0.25rem;
  max-width: 60%;
  align-self: flex-start;
  padding: 0.5rem;
  padding: 0.5rem 0.7rem;
  border-radius: 0.75rem;
  position: relative;
}

.bubble::after {
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    top: 50%;
    width: 0;
  height: 0;
  border: 12px solid transparent;
  border-right-color: #EEE;
  border-left: 0;
  border-top: 0;
  margin-top: -6px;
  margin-left: -12px;
  filter: drop-shadow(0px 1px 0px #DDD) drop-shadow(0px -1px 0px #DDD);
}

.bubble.right {
  border-color: #AAD;
  background: #EEF;
  align-self: flex-end;
}

.bubble.right::after {
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    top: 50%;
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
    border: 12px solid transparent;
  border-left-color: #EEF;
  border-right: 0;
    border-top: 0;
  margin-top: -6px;
  margin-right: -12px;
  filter: drop-shadow(0px 1px 0px #AAD) drop-shadow(0px -1px 0px #AAD);
  left: initial;
}

.bubble p {
  margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<div id="chat-container">
  <div class="bubble">
      <p>Hello Sam</p>
  </div>

  <div class="bubble right">
      <p>Hello Frodo</p>
  </div>

  <div class="bubble right">
      <p>Did you bring the ring?</p>
  </div>

  <div class="bubble">
      <p>What ring?</p>
  </div>

  <div class="bubble right">
      <p>The ring Frodo! The one that says Ash nazg durbatulûk, ash nazg gimbatul, Ash nazg thrakatulûk agh burzum-ishi krimpatul when heated.</p>
  </div>

  <div class="bubble">
      <p>Shut up Sam!</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Sadly no, the text needs to always be up to the right side of the page no matter the length. With your code it just pushes the text to the right a bit but not so that no matter the length it is always touching the right edge of the screen.

Comment: Hmm, so your conditions would be something like if it's one line, expand the text to the whole line, else if it's a multiple line text justify the first lines and align the last line to the right?

Comment: I do not want to use justify at all. The programme is for a chat interface with this specific code for the right side text. Example image: https://i.insider.com/5e16505cf4423166dc748173?width=1100&format=jpeg&auto=webp I need code for the blue text that keeps the text, no matter how long, on the right side of the screen.

Comment: Oh, than you need an entirely different structure. I'll update my answer.

Comment: I do think the renewed answer solves your issue @Anralore

Comment: Thank you. I have accepted the answer. I am new here so I was unaware that was possible.

Comment: You can also upvote answers indicating they were helpful.