# Private Chat Bubbles Go On Top of Each Other

Tags: html, css

I have a cloud storage/media/chatroom website (https://jazzythedog.awesomecrater.repl.co) that I recently added private chats. The messages you send go to the right and the ones other people send go to the left. But when I sent my second message it went over the first message.
Here is the CSS code:

```
.sent {
    position: absolute;
    background: blue;
  color: white;
  width: fit-content;
    border-radius: .4em;
  max-width: 300px;
  right: 20px;
  font-size: 18px;
  top: initial;
}

.sent:after {
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    top: 50%;
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
    border: 14px solid transparent;
    border-left-color: blue;
    border-right: 0;
    border-top: 0;
    margin-top: -7px;
    margin-right: -14px;
}


.got {
    position: absolute;
    background: #e8e8e8;
  color: black;
    border-radius: .4em;
  max-width: 300px;
  width: fit-content;
  left: 20px;
  font-size: 18px;
  top: initial;
}

.got:after {
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    top: 50%;
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
    border: 14px solid transparent;
    border-right-color: #e8e8e8;
    border-left: 0;
    border-top: 0;
    margin-top: -7px;
    margin-left: -14px;
}
```

Does anyone know how I can make them not overlap each other?

Comment: Hey there, a few months ago I helped another user with this example, you should probably change your structure, flex is really handy for use cases like chats, check this example and run the snippet https://stackoverflow.com/a/62493382/1169686

Comment: Absolute positioning the bubbles is messing things up. As Mihail mentioned, display flex would be quite helpful.